# Using wildcards in gmail (trying to auto block spam emails that have no unsubscribe button)

Tags: email, spam-prevention, regex

About a year ago, I started getting emails form very random email addresses that are just extremely obvious to be spam. However, just blocking one single user account doesn't do the trick because the source email changes all the time. There's no unsubscribe email.

I'm having a hard time wondering why Gmail doesn't support wildcards, or maybe I'm just using it wrong.

For example, the email ALWAYS copies an email such as `<MyName><RandomNumber>@aol.com` to its "to" "cc" list. However, I can't find a way to get rid of this in Gmail.

Adding in a search filter like `myname*@aol.com` doesn't work. I don't use AOL, but there are times where I get legitimate emails with other people copied on it who use AOL, so I can't completely look for just the aol.com domain. I also can't just use `myname@aol.com` because there are always random letters/numbers at the end of myname.

Is this seriously not possible in Gmail??

Comment: Related: [Petetion to enable wildcards in Gmail filters because SPAM](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/172093261/petetion-to-enable-wildcards-in-gmail-filters-because-spam?hl=en). Hint: you can't send a petition to Google but there are plenty of people who have the same problem as you.

Comment: Related: [What are the syntax rules for filters for the 'from' or 'to' fields? Partial names? Wildcards?](https://support.google.com/mail/thread/40293752/what-are-the-syntax-rules-for-filters-for-the-from-or-to-fields-partial-names-wildcards?hl=en#:~:text=All%20Replies%20(5)&text=Wildcards%20are%20not%20supported%20in,name%20with%20TLD%20should%20work.)

Comment: It is not possible.  For advanced searches you will need to use Google Apps Script